# Read terminal input in non blocking mode on Windows with PHP

Tags: php, windows

I'm trying to read in non blocking mode on Windows. The following working on linux does not work on Windows :

```
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);
$characters = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Any idea how to make it work? [Here is my whole code for context](https://gist.github.com/Nek-/119149c2b662ff9580e5d27261f83aef#file-console-php-L162).

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not allow it under windows because Windows does not support POSIX streams. It's only possible by using the C API directly. Lucky for me, PHP provides since PHP 7.4 a new API called FFI.

You can use the following C functions to do so:

- `GetStdHandle`: get a handle (think of it as a stream)
- `SetConsoleMode`: allow you to change the console mode (required, a possible value is `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`), you may want to restore the console mode afterwards but to do it you need to get it first by using `GetConsoleMode`
- `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`: there is no "non-blocking" function, but you can know if there's something in the buffer or not (in the case there is something in the buffer, the next function will not block)
- `ReadConsoleInput`: Get an array of buffered inputs. Please notice that this function is in fact `ReadConsoleInputW` or `ReadConsoleInputA` in the real API, ReadConsoleInput is just an alias.

You also need to define all the types those functions use. Due to the lack of documentation and huge amount of redefinitions of windef, this is hard. This is why I suggest you to take a look at the following gist that contains an example as well as all required definitions and many links where to find references.

https://gist.github.com/Nek-/118cc36d0d075febf614c53a48470490